# Insert record in mongoDB then update it - Node.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, collections, insert-update

I am new to nodeJS and MongoDB

I want to add a record to the database on the javascript event of PageLoad, then during the visit of the user i add values to this object and then update it in the collection depending on an ID i assigned to this record. I am doing it like the following:

Front-end :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async() => {

    var ID = function () {    
      return '_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    };

    jsLibrary.generateObject().then((objectName) => { 
        objectName.pageLoadTimeStamp = + new Date();
        objectName.identifier = ID;

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'/add',
                data:JSON.stringify(objectName),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
                }); 
});

window.onpagehide = function(){         
        objectName.PageHideTimeStamp = + new Date();

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'/update',
            data:JSON.stringify(objectName),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        })           
    };
```

As you can see i am assigning an ID to an object i'm receiving from a library, then logging the timestamp for pageload and sending it back-end to add it to the database. Then on the event of pageHide I am saving the timestamp of the user leaving the page, and i want to update the record in the collection to re-add it depending on its ID

Back-end: My app.js file

```
app.post('/add', function(req, res) 
{  
    objName  = (req.body);

    db.components.insert(objName, function(err,res)
            {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err); }
                console.log("SUCCESS");
    });
});

app.post('/update', function(req, res) 
{  
    objName  = (req.body); 

    db.components.update( { identifier: objName.identifier }, objName, true )

    console.log("updated");
 });
```

I get on my console both the values `SUCCESS` and `updated`

But when i check the values in my collection; they don't seem to be updated. The `pageHideTimeStamp` doesn't exist.

The problem is probably with the update, I  want to replace the whole record with a new one depending on the ID.

IS there a better practice? Sorry i'm new to this. Thank you

PS: its not practical for me to pass through every parameter i added to this object while updating. There are other parameters I'm adding other than PageHideTimeStamp and there could be more with time

Answer (score 0):

the condition for updating should have only the check you need to apply like it should be , 
let cond = {'id' : '22'} or cond = {'name' : 'sss'} , 
you are using req.body whole object as condition you can try code like this

```
db.update(condition,data,this.table,function (err,refresh) {
        if(err){
            //console.log('err controler', refresh)
            callback(err, null);
            return;
        }
        //console.log('updated ', refresh)
        callback(null,refresh);


});
```

Comment: I am using the value of 'identifier' in my req.body as a condition, not the whole object :  `{ identifier : obj.identifier } `

Answer (score 0):

Use `$set` for update data

```
     db.components.update( { identifier: objName.identifier }, {$set : objName},function(err,result){
  console.log('updated')
})
```

Comment: If you want to update multiple records use { multi : true } param after $set object